# What is the fastest way to Initialize a priority_queue from an unordered_set

Tags: c++11, stl

It is said in [construction of a priority queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) , option (12):

```
template< class InputIt >
priority_queue( InputIt first, InputIt last,
                const Compare& compare = Compare(), 
                Container&& cont = Container() );
```

But I don't know how ot use this.
I have a non-empty `std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>> mySet`, and I want to convert it to a priority queue. I also create a comparator struct `MyComparator`:

```
struct MyComparator {
  bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<myStruct>& a, 
                  const std::shared_ptr<myStruct>& b){...}
};
```

Now how can I construct a new priority_queue `myQueue` in a better way? I used the following and it works:

```
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>, std::deque<std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>, MyComparator> 
    myQueue(mySet.begin(), mySet.end());
```

I benchmarked both vector and deque, and I find deque will outperform vector when the size is relatively large (~30K).
Since we have already known the size of `mySet`, I should create the deque with that size. But how can I create this priority_queue with my own comparator and predefined deque, say `myDeque`?

Comment: Are you going to insert more elements into the priority queue afterward?

Comment: Yes, the algorithm will pop the heaviest one, check its status, and may add more objects related to that heaviest one. This kind of insertion could probably occur many times( about half of the original size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already determined that `std::deque` gives you better performance than `std::vector`, I don't think there is much more you can do in terms of how you construct the `priority_queue`.  As you have probably seen, there is no `std::deque::reserve()` method, so it's simply not possible to create a deque with memory allocated ahead of time.  For most use cases this is not a problem, because the main feature of deque vs vector is that deque does not need to copy elements as new ones are inserted.

If you are still not achieving the performance you desire, you might consider either storing raw pointers (keeping your smart pointers alive outside), or simply changing your `unordered_map` to a regular `map` and relying on the ordering that container provides.